# Model foreach element name generate incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I generate a partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.vm_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => item.AnswerShownOrder, item.AnswerShownOrder.ToString(), new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.AnswerOptionText, new { @class = "form-control", @id = item.PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID })


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.CorrectAnswer, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "chk" + item.PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID })

            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

when but created control's name start with item.please see bellow image
[image] 
in class I have 2 properties

```
public ICollection<string> AnswerOptionText { get; set; }
        public ICollection<bool> CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
```

and values are not mapped if names are generate like this.

why its generate like this?and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below in your model class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Whatever name you want to assign to it")]
public ICollection<string> AnswerOptionText { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the property which is still a collection of string. You need another for loop before you can see the display:

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.vm_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => item.AnswerShownOrder, item.AnswerShownOrder.ToString(), new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })

    @foreach (var itemAnswer in item.AnswerOptionText)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => itemAnswer, new { @class = "form-control", @id = item.PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID })
        </div>
     }
}
```

You need to do the for loop as well on the `ICollection CorrectAnswer` property. Lastly, it is not a good idea to have a collection of model with a collection of property. Either you declare one model to your cshtml view with different collections like this one:

```
@model vm_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions
```

With collection of properties attached to it:

```
public ICollection<string> AnswerOptionText { get; set; }
public ICollection<bool> CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
```

And not this one which is harder to maintain especially if it contains collection of properties:

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.vm_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions>
```